# SQL: Counting aggregates?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this question, which is part of the reason I am having problems producing or finding an answer.

Given the following table:

| id | class | region_id | rank | irrelevant_column_1_of_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | class1 | A | over | irrelevant value |
| 2 | class1 | A | over |  |
| 3 | class1 | A | under |  |
| 4 | class1 | B | over |  |
| 5 | class1 | B | over |  |
| 6 | class1 | C | under |  |

How can the following report be produced for each row where `class=class1`

```
(region_id=A, over_count: 2, under_count: 1),
(region_id=B, over_count: 2, under_count: 0),
(region_id=C, over_count: 0, under_count: 1),
```

My SQL is basic. I tried `GROUP BY`, but can't get it do more than:

```
(A, over, 2),
(A, under, 1),
(B, over, 2),
(B, under, 0),
(C, over, 0),
(C, under, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filtered aggregation:

```
select region_id, 
       count(*) filter (where rank = 'over') as over_count,
       count(*) filter (where rank = 'under') as under_count
from the_table
where class = 'class1'
group by region_id
```

Answer (score 1):

A method that I've used a fair bit in MS SQL Server which I think will work directly in postgres is to `SUM` based on `CASE` expressions:

```sql
  SELECT region_id
       , SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 'over'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS over_count
       , SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 'under' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS under_count
    FROM your_table
GROUP BY region_id
```